# How can i get multiple resultset from a stored procedure in java

Tags: java, mysql, json, jdbc, resultset

My task is to get multiple resultsets from a stored procedure & return as json object along with model number, but unfortunately i'm getting only first resultset

to get multiple resultset i'm trying to do something like

```
        boolean isResultExists = false;
        isResultExists = callableStatement.execute();

        resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();
        resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            mapObject = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
                mapObject.put(resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i),
                        resultSet.getObject(i));

            listOfProperties.add(mapObject);
            // isResultExists = callableStatement.getMoreResults();
        }
```

this code is returning only 1st resultset & if i try to use

```
isResultExists = callableStatement.getMoreResults();
```

I'm getting

> java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"
>   Exception

Can anybody suggest best way to get multiple resultset & convert to json Objects

Thanks in advance

Comment: please have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149672/jdbctemplate-multiple-result-sets)

Comment: You might want to look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213824/java-sql-statement-hasresultset/14413141

Comment: Thank you for valuable suggestions, can anyone post answer for same