JdbcTemplate swallows permission errors on compound commands
We are trying to validate that SQL "where" fragments supplied by users does not have any "write" side effects or other SQL injection. We are doing this by running the commands over a SQL connection which has read only access and catching any exceptions. This works for single commands, but for a compound statement we see JdbcTemplate logging debug messages about SQLExceptions but no exception is thrown.
This will throw a SQLException:
jdbcTemplate.execute("drop table students;")

this will not:
jdbcTemplate.execute("select 1 where 1=1; drop table students;")

though it will log the same errors in DEBUG log. Here are the debug level logs when the second statement is run:
SqlVerifierController             : Running Sql: select count(*) as numResults from dbo.tbtCloudDialingToImport where 1=1;drop table students;
jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate            : Executing SQL statement [select count(*) as numResults from dbo.tbtCloudDialingToImport where 1=1;drop table students;]
jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils   : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement : SQLServerStatement:10 created by (ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 93203efc-9061-4f6e-9501-61a788096f57)
jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement : SQLServerStatement:10 Executing (not server cursor) SELECT 1
jdbc.internals.SQLServerResultSet : SQLServerResultSet:10 created by (SQLServerStatement:10)
jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement : SQLServerStatement:11 created by (ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 93203efc-9061-4f6e-9501-61a788096f57)
jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement : SQLServerStatement:11 Executing (not server cursor) select count(*) as numResults from dbo.tbtCloudDialingToImport where 1=1;drop table students;
jdbc.internals.SQLServerResultSet : SQLServerResultSet:11 created by (SQLServerStatement:11)
jdbc.internals.SQLServerException : *** SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot drop the table 'students', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Cannot drop the table 'students', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
SqlVerifierController             : Running Sql: select top(2) TRIM(AccountNumber) from dbo.tbtCloudDialingToImport where 1=1;drop table students;
jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate            : Executing SQL query [select top(2) TRIM(AccountNumber) from dbo.tbtCloudDialingToImport where 1=1;drop table students;]
jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils   : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement : SQLServerStatement:12 created by (ConnectionID:1 ClientConnectionId: 93203efc-9061-4f6e-9501-61a788096f57)
jdbc.internals.SQLServerStatement : SQLServerStatement:12 Executing (not server cursor) select top(2) TRIM(AccountNumber) from dbo.tbtCloudDialingToImport where 1=1;drop table students;
jdbc.internals.SQLServerResultSet : SQLServerResultSet:12 created by (SQLServerStatement:12)
SQLServerResultSetMetaData        :  SQLServerResultSetMetaData:2 created by (SQLServerResultSet:12)
jdbc.internals.SQLServerException : *** SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot drop the table 'students', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Cannot drop the table 'students', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Similar logging about "Cannot drop the table 'students'" occurs in the SQL Server machine.
setting "ignoreWarnings" to false on the jdbcTemplate has no effect.
The version of jdbcTemplate is from org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.1
We have examined the JdbcTemplate, the connection, we have tried different methods of excecuting the SQL statement, we have examined resultsets, nothing gives us any indication of the SQL exceptions in the compound statement.
If the compound statement is syntactically incorrect then we will get an exception. This will throw an exception:
jdbcTemplate.execute("select 1 where 1=1; bogus SQL statement;")

We would like valid compound statements which do not have permission to run to throw an exception, or at least give us some feedback that there was an exception other than capturing debug logs.

I believe this is due the SQL Server jdbc driver implementation. The reason the error doesn't show when there are two valid commands is that it allows you to run batch statements and only consider the batch invalid if all commands fail (that's why you get an exception logged for when just the select works), however the second command with the bogus statement fails immediately because there is a parse process before the batches executes. Try setting SET XACT_ABORT ON; doc

Thanks @JorgeCampos for that excellent suggestion. It did not work. The following returns no errors: "SET XACT_ABORT ON; BEGIN TRANSACTION; select 1 where 1=1; drop table students; COMMIT TRANSACTION;" but if I remove the "select 1 where 1=1" then it throws an exception. I have tried several methods of enforcing a transaction. We have found a solution, posting it now, thanks!

How will this "verification" help you against a smart adversary. I can do: if @@servername or username control before executing drop table and it will skip doing anything on read only connection and only do things in write only one.

@siggemannen because the verification process will only have read only access. If it comes back with an exception or with more than one resultset it won't be allowed to be saved as a fragment available in the admin app

An if condition will not fail because it won't perform the dangerous operation

We have found the following query will return a resultset for each of the SQL statements (so 2 in this case, "select 1" and "drop table students"), and we can examine each resultset to see if there is an error:
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1; drop table students;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT
          ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        , ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        , ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        , ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        , ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        , ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
    ;
END CATCH

and was easily queried with the following Java statement:
Map<String,Object> resultSets = jdbcTemplate.call(con -> con.prepareCall(sql), new ArrayList<>());


multiple resultset query credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/143139/tomaszkubacki for one of the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149672
